# Excel visual basic function across workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, visual-basic

This seems like it should be a common issue, but I couldn't find anything on it, maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing.

Basically I get sent a lot of workbooks that need specific modifications done to them, so I decided to write a little vb function to do it, I even attached it to the ribbon.  The issue is that the function only exists in the one Workbook, so when I click the icon in the ribbon on another workbook it throws an error saying the function can't be found (obviously).

Is there anyway I can attach a function not to the workbook, but to my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is Excel's **Personal Macro Workbook** function, which allows you to store your frequently used macros in a special hidden workbook that makes them available in any workbooks you have open.

[Here's how it works.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx)